# Modelo SHOW devuelve error 404

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Controlador con modelo show devuelve error 404.

Controlador:

```
Route::get('/preguntas/{categoria}', 'PreguntaController@show');
```

El controlador contiene el siguiente modelo show:

```
public function show(categoria $categoria)
    {
       dd($categoria);
    }
```

El enlace para disparar:

```
<a class="portfolio-link" href="{{ url('/preguntas/animales') }}">Animales</a>
```

Comment: La información que tratas de obtener corresponde solo al modelo `Pregunta`?

Comment: Así es. Sólo corresponde al modelo Pregunta. Hay una tabla de preguntas que contiene columnas: pregunta, categoria, etc. Corresponde al modelo pregunta. Un saludo Aprendiz.

Comment: por url no estas pasando el id si no el nombre de que?, es decir en lugar de la columna id cual es la que estas ocupando?

Comment: Por url estoy pasando una de las columnas de la tabla preguntas. Ya que según la categoría, después (de momento sólo hago prueba con dd($categoria) para ver si llega) mostrará unas preguntas u otras.

Answer (score 1):

Considero que deberías proceder del modo siguiente:

Asignarle un nombre a tu ruta de este modo:

```
Route::get('/preguntas/{pregunta}', 'PreguntaController@show')->name('preguntas.show');
```

Como no estas usando la llave primaria para obtener los datos de un registros en específico, entonces debemos aclarar esto en el modelo `Pregunta` así:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'categoria';
}
```

En el modelo usamos el método [`getRouteKeyname()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding), donde en el `return` indicamos la nueva columna que usaremos para llevar a cabo el filtro.

Ahora dentro del controller `PreguntaController.php` creo que debería ser de este modo:

```
public function show(Pregunta $pregunta)
{
    dd($pregunta);
}
```

Es decir:

- Como argumentos del método `show` debes pasar el nombre de clase del Modelo Pregunta, pues finalmente es de este mismo del cual deseas recuperar la información
- Como segundo argumento pasas una propiedad llamada `$pregunta`.

Finalmente en la vista si tienes múltiples valores que iteras con un `foreach` deberas hacer esto:

```
<a class="portfolio-link" href="{{ route('preguntas.show', $pregunta->categoria) }}">Animales</a>
```

Lo anterior de modo tal que cuando des click al enlace anterior te lleve a una nueva vista con los datos filtrados de un registro en particular.

Comment: Muchas gracias por toda la explicación tan detallada Aprendiz. He modificado según me indicas. Pero en la vista inicial me devuelve error: "Undefined variable: pregunta". Posiblemente me he explicado mal yo. Hay una tabla de preguntas que contiene una columna llamada categoria. Por eso en la URL de cada enlace (a href) llevará como atributo un nombre de categoria.

Comment: ¿Dónde la debería declarar? Así lo he puesto, eso es: Por ejemplo para el botón que lleva a pregunta de animales: {{ route('preguntas.show', $pregunta->animales) }} Y para el botón que lleva a pregunta de casa: {{ route('preguntas.show', $pregunta->casa) }} ¿Es así?

Comment: Perfecto, en la tabla de preguntas, el nombre de la columna  a la que nos referimos se llama "categoria". Y los datos de esa columa nos: Animales, Casa, Saludos, etc.

Comment: <a class="portfolio-link" href="{{ route('preguntas.show', $pregunta->categoria) }}">Animales</a> Pero de esta manera no le indicamos "animales" o lo que sea a la route. ¿no? Parece que debería ser: <a class="portfolio-link" href="{{ route('preguntas.show', $pregunta->animales) }}">Animales</a> ¿Qué opinas?

Comment: Perdona mi mala explicación. Entiendo lo que pretendes. Crep que tú quieres mostrar contenido de la columna. llamada categoria con: {{ route('preguntas.show', $pregunta->categoria) }}. Yo lo que pretendo es que en la página principal tengo varios enlaces, y que esos enlaces contengan "/preguntas/animales" otro contenga "/preguntas/casa" y en al modelo show llegue la palabra "animales" o la palabra "casa" o la que tenga. (No pretendo sacar nada de la base de datos de momento). Simplemente en el modelo Show hacer un dd para ver el parámetro llegar.

Comment: Pequeño gran detalle, en cuanto tenga tiempo modifico mi respuesta

Comment: Que soy yo, que no me he explicado bien seguramente. Agradecería esa modificación, muchas gracias Aprendiz. ; )